# Jquery Fade-in/out doesn't work on element

Tags: jquery, fade

I built jquery function that need to fade in\out my signup form, the function works while I am using it on new page, but it doesn't work on my website.
Here is the code of the function:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        if ($("#signupform").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#signupform").fadeIn()
        }
        else {
            $("#signupform").fadeOut()
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the page that the function doesn't work on it:
http://pastebin.com/xXV4M9Us

Answer (score 0):

Use `:visible`,

```
if ($("#signupform").is(":visible")) {
            $("#signupform").fadeIn()
        }
else {
            $("#signupform").fadeOut()
     }
```